# How to prepend directory to all file names stored inside of '$^' variable

Tags: makefile

I am trying to use the `ar` command to build a library from some `.o` files, and these `.o` files are stored in a variable like this:

```
OBJS    := foo.o bar.o baz.o
```

and I have a rule for building the library that looks like this:

```
libfoo.a: $(OBJS)
    $(AR) rcs $(LIBDIR)/$@ $^
```

however this doesn't work because all these objects files are stored inside of a separate bin directory and so make can't find them. Something like this obviously doesn't work:

```
libfoo.a: $(OBJS)
    $(AR) rcs $(LIBDIR)/$@ $(BINDIR)/$^
```

so how can I tell make to look for these object files in a different directory without having to cd?

Comment: notice this makefile is broken since it'll look for libfoo.a in CWD and create the archive in $(LIBDIR)/libfoo.a, causing libfoo.a to always be out of date (missing) and rebuilt. A correct makefile would have $(LIBDIR)/libfoo.a as target and $@ in the recipe. Same goes for prerequisites: never prefix them with path in the recipe.

Comment: @Andreas thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility: prepend a dir to all obj and either overwrite `OBJS` or replace usage of `OBJS` with a new symbol:

```
OBJS := foo.o bar.o baz.o
SUBDIR_OBJS := $(OBJS:%=subdir/%)

show:
    @echo OBJS $(OBJS)
    @echo SUBDIR_OBJS $(SUBDIR_OBJS)
```

For more info about substitutions, see gnu [text functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)

Comment: gnu file name functions has addprefix: `$(addprefix obj/, $(OBJS))`. Does the same thing, possibly being more readable than plain pattern substitution.